# python implementing a black scholes model equation

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I'm keep getting -0.08125 instead of 0.175

can anyone see what im doing wrong with my code ?

Here is my code below

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy import log as ln
import math



class BSOption:

    def __init__(self,s,x,t,sigma,rf,div):
        """ definition for the base case BSOption constructor
        """
        self.s = s #current stock price in dollars
        self.x = x #the option strike price
        self.t = t #the option maturity time in years
        self.sigma = sigma #the annualized standard drviation of returns
        self.rf = rf #the annualized risk free rate of return
        self.div = div #the annualized dividend rate; 

    def __repr__(self):
        """ repr method to print out the values nicely
        """
        s=""
        s+= "s = " + "$"+ str(self.s) +".00,"
        s+=" x = " + "$" + str(self.x)+".00,"
        s+= " t = " + str(self.t) +" (years),"
        s+="  sigma = " + str(self.sigma)+"00,"
        s+=" rf = " + str(self.rf)+"0,"
        s+=" div = "+ str(self.div)+"0"

        return s

    def d1(self):
        """helper method to get d1 with given formula
        """#np.log = ln

        numinator = (ln((self.s / self.x)) + (self.rf - self.sigma + 
                     ((1/2) * (self.sigma)**(2))) * self.t)

        result= numinator / (self.sigma) * (math.sqrt(self.t))
        return result
```

I'm testing method d1

with

option = BSOption(100, 100, 0.25, 0.3, 0.06, 0.00)

option.d1()
option.d1() => should return 0.175 but im keep getting -0.08

I've tried to write it in different format but im keep getting the same result

Below is the equation that i need to implement for d1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzgHU.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
result= numinator / (self.sigma) * (math.sqrt(self.t))
```

`x / y * z` is not equivalent to `x / (y * z)`; in the order of operations, multiplication and division are performed in the same pass.

A good way to avoid these kinds of problems is to use more names to refer to sub-expressions. You had the right idea factoring out a `numerator` (note spelling); you could do the same for the `denominator`. (Or if these quantities have actual names in the literature, use those!)